# How to plot a 2D Dirac function sequence in 3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

The goal is simple: to show users, visually, how the Dirac function $\delta(x,y)$ differs from $\delta(x-y)$.

The approach is to pick a term from a sequence like this

```
seq1[x_, y_,ϵ_] :=  1/π ϵ/(x^2 + y^2 + ϵ^2)
```

and use `Plot3D`. The attempt to find the right settings for the mesh, lighting, perspective, etc. has proven futile.

Comment: @Maple SE - Area 51 Proposal: A quick library of sequences. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Plot3D[
 {(1/π .3)/(x^2 + y^2 + .3^2),
   (1/π .1)/(x^2 + y^2 + .1^2),
  (1/π .03)/(x^2 + y^2 + .03^2)},
 {x, -.2, .2}, {y, -.2, .2},
 PlotRange -> {0, 6},
 PlotStyle ->
  {{Opacity[1], Purple}, 
   {Opacity[0.5] , Green}, 
   {Opacity[0.1], Yellow}}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Comment: Very impressive.

Answer (score 3):

```
seq1[x_, y_, ϵ_] := 1/π ϵ/(x^2 + y^2 + ϵ^2)

Plot3D[Evaluate[ seq1[x, y, #] & /@ {0.3, 0.1, 0.03}], {x, -.2, .2}, {y, -.2, .2}, 
              PlotRange -> {0, 6}, PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[1], Red}, {Opacity[0.5], Green}, 
             {Opacity[0.3], Blue}}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]